# Портится качество изображения в галерее WordPress

Tags: wordpress, изображения, jpeg

Пользуюсь плагином Elementor. Вставил 3 галереи, во всех  качество изображений, которые я в них поместил, резко ухудшается. Изначально на сайт загрузил изображения типа image/jpeg, размером 2300x3200 px.Вставил галерею из чужого шаблона, такой проблемы не наблюдаю.

В чем заключается проблема потеря качества?

Comment: В криво настроенных библиотеках обработки графики. Это вопрос не к ВП.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress по умолчанию сжимает все загружаемые изображения,  надо в functions.php прописать: `add_filter('jpeg_quality', function($arg){return 100;});`

Comment: Это не поможет, в ядре по умолчанию качество стоит 82% или 90%, в разных ситуациях. Разницы со 100% вы не заметите. Проблема в неправильных размераз миниатюр.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, а где это можно настроить?

Comment: `wp-admin/options-media.php` - ну а так надо смотреть ваш проект и разбираться, какие размеры применяются в галерее.